# Expand and contract tableview cell when tapped, in swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm trying to expand a tableview cell when tapped. Then, when it is tapped again, I want it to go back to its original state.

If cellA is expanded and cellB is tapped, I want cellA to contract and cellB to expand at the same time. So that only one cell can be in its expanded state in any given moment.

My current code:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {
   var isCellTapped = false
   var currentRow = -1


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        selectedRowIndex = indexPath
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex.row {
        if isCellTapped == false {
            isCellTapped = true
            return 140
        } else if isCellTapped == true {
            isCellTapped = false
            return 70
        }

    }

    return 70
}
```

Current code works well when:

- You tap a row (it expands)
- You tap it again (it contracts)

It fails when:

- You tap a row (it expands)
- You tap another row (it contracts, but the other row does not expand)

How can I solve this?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve? An accordion menu (dropdown menu) using a `UITableView`?

Comment: Yes @VictorSigler, something like that. Do you think in can be done using UITableView? Or are there any other classes that are more suited to the task?

Comment: Yes you can @Diego see my answer.

Comment: @VictorSigler one thing I really need is the "expanded" state to be a property of only a cell at any given moment. If cellA is expanded and cellB is tapped, cellA must contract and cellB expand.

Comment: You can do it without any problem,  see my updated answer, but nevertheless I strongly recommend you see my repo to know more about the accordion menu using an `UITableView`

Comment: i am trying to do something similar, what do you mean by selectedIndexPath here at diego? pardon me. i am new to swift.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to take in account that you need to update your selected row when another is tapped, see the following code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
        return 140
    }
    return 44
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if selectedRowIndex != indexPath.row {

        // paint the last cell tapped to white again
        self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0))?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        // save the selected index 
        self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row

        // paint the selected cell to gray
        self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

        // update the height for all the cells
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

> **EDIT:**

To handle that the cell where is selected and is tapped again return to its original state you need to check some conditions like the following:

```
var thereIsCellTapped = false
var selectedRowIndex = -1

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex && thereIsCellTapped {
        return 140
    }

    return 44
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()

    // avoid paint the cell is the index is outside the bounds
    if self.selectedRowIndex != -1 {
        self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: self.selectedRowIndex, inSection: 0))?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    if selectedRowIndex != indexPath.row {
        self.thereIsCellTapped = true
        self.selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
    }
    else {
        // there is no cell selected anymore
        self.thereIsCellTapped = false
        self.selectedRowIndex = -1
    }

    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

With the above modifications in your`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath` functions you can see when a cell is tapped its background color it will be changed to gray when it's height grow and when another cell is tapped the cell is painted to white and the tapped to gray and again and again allowing only tap one cell at time.

I though you can benefit and learn how to do a **Accordion Menu** in this [repo](https://github.com/Vkt0r/AccordionMenu) I have created and I plan to update very soon to handle better results, it's handle using a `UITableView` just like you want.

Any doubt in the repository you can post it here.

I hope this help you.

Comment: I'm getting two errors with your code: "NSIndexPath is not convertible to int" and "cannot assign value of Int to a value of type NSIndexPath". These occur when trying to "paint the cell tapped to white again" and then when "saving the selected index". Any clue?

Comment: I solved those two problems, just a dumb error on my part. My problem is that now. Your code works well now, but when tapping an already expanded cell the cell does not go back to its original (contracted) state.

Comment: @DiegoPetrucci See my updated answer to clarify your doubts.

Comment: @VictorSigler, is there any way that I can do the cell still expand until it was selected back? Because using your code, it expand selected cell but, it turn back to original when other cell is selected.

Comment: @ThihaAung In this case the answer was to support only one cell expanded at time, but you can check my code in this repository for more information https://github.com/Vkt0r/AccordionMenuSwift

Answer (score 8):

A simple approach for expanding only one cell at a time:

**Swift 3**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {  

var selectedRowIndex = -1  
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedRowIndex {
            return 90 //Expanded
        }
        return 40 //Not expanded
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if selectedRowIndex == indexPath.row {
            selectedRowIndex = -1
        } else {
            selectedRowIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

This code will expand the clicked cell and close previously open cell with animation.

Comment: Thanks it works very well, when I tried to put a breakpoint in "return 90 //Expanded" statement it executed was 3 times, can you please tell me why?

Comment: Height for row executes for each row in the table

Comment: @MarkKazakov Possible can I ask one question related to expandable cells?

Comment: @Newbie yes sure

Comment: @MarkKazakov Thank you. This is my question link how can I achieve this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637065/how-to-make-xib-footer-items-clickable-in-tableview-swift?noredirect=1#comment109029064_61637065

Comment: @MarkKazakov Thanks for this solution. I used your approach in my application and getting some small issue like, expanded cell items getting override on top of the parent cell items. Can you please help me to resolve this issue would appreciate..

Answer (score -1):

## **UITableViewCell**:

```
import UIKit

protocol HierarchyTableViewCellDelegate {
   func didTapOnMoreButton(cell:HierarchyTableViewCell)
}

class HierarchyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var viewBtn: UIButton!

//MARK:- CONSTANT(S)
var delegate:HierarchyTableViewCellDelegate!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}
@IBAction func actionViewButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
     delegate.didTapOnMoreButton(cell: self)
 }
}
```

## UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewObj: UITableView!
var HierarchyListArr = NSArray()
var selectedIndex:Int?

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return HierarchyListArr.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewObj.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HierarchyTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HierarchyTableViewCell
    cell.delegate = self
 if let index = selectedIndex,indexPath.row == index{
        cell.viewBtn.isSelected = true
    }else{
        cell.viewBtn.isSelected = false
    }

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if let index = selectedIndex,indexPath.row == index{
        return 190
    }
    return 80
}
}

extension ViewController: HierarchyTableViewCellDelegate{
func didTapOnMoreButton(cell: HierarchyTableViewCell) {
    guard let index = tableViewObj.indexPath(for: cell)else{return}
    if selectedIndex == index.row{
        selectedIndex = -1
    }else{
        selectedIndex = index.row
    }
    tableViewObj.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .fade)
}
}
```