# Hide unhide Static Table View Cells with Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I am trying to make a '''Static Table''' with some cells that are expandable and collapsing . I override the ''': WithAnimation:)''' which should provide me some control on the animation transition. Unfortunately, the cells returned are blank, I don't mean empty, but the cells have disappeared and their location is left blanc in the table. When I try using the '''reloadSections( )''' rather, the whole section  is also returned blank. After some recherche , I start to suspect that '''reloadRowAtIndexPath(​: WithAnimation:)''' and '''reloadSections( )''' works with table associated with a data source.
Am I right? If yes, how can I control animation of the cell I want to hide/unhide so that the transition is smooth? 
Thanks (edited)

Comment: How you are going to hide cell? We can not play much with the static table view, instead i would suggest you to use prototype table view and then you can use deleteRowsAtIndexPaths and insertRowsAtIndexPaths with the animation you want.

Comment: Thanks but I have to use a static table for the purpose of my application

Comment: Could you provide the code that you are using to hide and show the cells?

Comment: You can find a complete answer to this question here: [Expand and contract tableview cell when tapped, in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818169/expand-and-contract-tableview-cell-when-tapped-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a smooth animation, simply reload the tableView with

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.endUpdates()
```

this will call the heightForRowAtIndexPath automatically and render a smooth transition.

Comment: Above was true until < iOS 15.0. As of iOS 15.0, you have to ``reloadData()`` before, otherwise the expand doesn't work (animated collapse still works w/o). The complete code would be: ``tableView.reloadData()``, ``tableView.beginUpdates(), ``tableView.endUpdates()``

Answer (score 2):

To expand on irkinosor's answer. In this example I have 1 section with 3 static rows. When tableView is initially loaded, my UISwitch is off and I only want the first row (row 0) be visible (hide rows 1,2). When the UISwitch is on, I want to show (rows 1,2). Also, I want smooth animation having the rows accordion to hide or show.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row > 0 && toggleSwitch.isOn == false {
        return 0.0  // collapsed
    }
    // expanded with row height of parent
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

In my switch action I initiate the tableView refresh

```
@IBAction func reminderSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    // to initiate smooth animation
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

You can obviously add more logic to the heightForRowAt function if you have multiple sections and more interesting row requirements.

Comment: Above works as described until iOS 14.0, but as of iOS 15.0, the collapse still works as before, but the expand doesn't work. In fact, a swipe down/up forces refresh of tableview section and the expanded row now shows properly. However if expanded row should be in view, it doesn't expand anymore like prior iOS 15.0.

Comment: Animation works as expected in iOS 15, tried and tested.