# Expanding a UIView in a UITableViewCell as well as the cell itself on click

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableViewCell with three Views. I'm using AutoLayout and UITableViewAutomaticDimension for the rowHeight. What I want to achieve is that when a user clicks on a cell, the blue view as well as the whole TableViewCell gets expanded (animated), like this ...

[image] [image]

I couldn't come up with an idea to solve this, does anyone has a hint?

Comment: This link may be helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818169/expand-and-contract-tableview-cell-when-tapped-in-swift