# How to make Xib footer items Clickable in tableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib

I am struggling to make my footer items clickable in tableView.
In tableView I am using two different Xib's and I have used `tableView - didSelect function` as a expandable cell on click.

1) Main Xib

2) Child_View - Footer Xib

Now on footer items which is childView - I also want to make clickable action so on clicking it will `navigate to viewController` with their detail information.

- How can I achieve this because didSelect is already in use for expandable cells?

Attaching three images

- Main Xib
- Expanded - Footer items (second Xib)
- Highlighted one needs to be clickable

declare : `var selectedIndex : Int! = -1`

Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == selectedIndex{
            selectedIndex = -1

        }else{
            selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.row == selectedIndex
        {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }else{
            return 71
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 1 
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DownloadEntryViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DownloadEntryViewCell
        let dic = Appdata?[indexPath.row]
        var stackHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        cell.fileNameLabel.text = dic?.date

        for i in Appdata ?? [] {
            let child_view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FooterView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FooterView
            child_view.projName.text = "\(i.projectName ?? "")" + "  " + "\(i.subTitle ?? "")"

            cell.stackViewFooter.addArrangedSubview(child_view)
            stackHeight = stackHeight + 60.0

        }
        cell.stackViewFooter.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: stackHeight).isActive = true
        return cell
    }
```

Images:

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAUnG.png)  [Expandable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdQOi.png)  [clickable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gWn9.png)

Comment: Create a new function wherever your footer is created. Then add something like this `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)`

Comment: @xTwisteDx Thank you. But Thing its based on `Appdata` and I have to handle error. If there is any error like not properly downloaded for any reason then It will be clickable and navigate to next viewController.

Comment: @xTwisteDx Do you mean `tapGesture` on footer label ?